# Trying TRIE DS implementation

Tags: data-structures, trie

So, I'tried implementing TRIE DS, and while the node in the tree gets the value of Words assigned after addWord ends, but when I traverse the tree, The value that prints is zero. What did I do wrong, unable to point out. Please can someone help.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>

    using namespace std;

    struct trie{
        int words;
        int prefixes;
        trie* edges[26];
    };

    void addWord(trie* vertex, string word){

        if(word.length() == 0){
            vertex->words = vertex->words + 1;
        }
        else{
            // cout<<word<<endl;
            vertex->prefixes = vertex->prefixes + 1;
            char k = word[0];
            if(vertex->edges[k - 'a'] == NULL){
                trie *n = (trie*)malloc(sizeof(trie));
                n->words = 0;
                n->prefixes = 0;
                for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
                    vertex->edges[i] = NULL;
                vertex->edges[k - 'a'] = n;
            }
            word.erase(0, 1);
            addWord(vertex->edges[k - 'a'], word);
        }
    };
    void traverse(trie *vertex){
        if(vertex != NULL){
            for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
                if(vertex->edges[i] != NULL){
                    traverse(vertex->edges[i]);
                    cout<<char(i+'a')<<" - "<<vertex->prefixes<< " : "<<vertex->words<<endl;
                }
            }
        }

    };


    int main(){
        string word = "hello";
        trie* head = (trie*)malloc(sizeof(trie));
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
            head->edges[i] = NULL;
        head->words = 0;
        head->prefixes = 0;
        addWord(head, word);
        string s = "lo";
        traverse(head);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you single-stepped the code in your debugger to see where it's going off track? If not, then I'd say that's what you've done wrong.

Comment: @JimMischel, any particular suggestion pls, specially for simple one-file c/c++?

Comment: Suggestion for what? My specific suggestion is that you start your debugger and single-step the code so you can see where it's not doing what you expect. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now's the perfect time to learn.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with code:

1. In your `addWord` function, inside `else` block, in the `for` loop, change `vertex->edges[i] = NULL;` to `n->edges[i] = NULL;`
2. The problem you asked for is in your `traverse` function. You are not printing the `words` count for node pointed by say last `o`, you  are printing it for the node that have `o` as it's edge. So just change this:

   `cout<<char(i+'a')<<" - "<<vertex->prefixes<< " : "<<vertex->words<<endl;`

to this:

```
cout<<char(i+'a')<<" - "<<vertex->edges[i]->prefixes<< " : "<<vertex->edges[i]->words<<endl;
```